# AS3 Event listeners when data is changed?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Hopefully you will excuse me if this is a simple/silly question.  I started learning action script about 6 days ago and already working on a small project :D

Anyways, there is a property that changes occasionally to reflect the name of a level in a game (object._I._M.text).  It could take a minute to change, or a max of two minutes, depending on how fast all players are able to finish the level.

I want to be able to listen for the change in this property to fire off another function.  I have found very few answers to this online, and the examples I have found were very incomplete and poorly written.  Does anyone know how I could do this?

I have tried ...

theobject._I._M.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, myfunction);

To no success.  Thanks for any help or advice, I am going to get back to learning while I await responses :D

Comment: Is `object._I._M` a `TextField`/built-in type or is it a user-defined type?

Answer (score 3):

I would probably use getters/setters, or just declare one method to change the text of that textfield so that you can dispatch an event every time.

```
function changeLevel(text:String):void {
   levelTf.text=text;
   dispatchEvent(new Event("levelChange"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll agree the Adobe docs are a bit "heavy" to look through. A good resource is the [kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/forum) forum.

As for the `TextField` change event listener, your original code is very close. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/TextField/AddchangeeventtoTextField.htm) is a good example of how to add an event listener. The basics are:

```
public class Main extends Sprite {
  // Store a reference to the text field
  // (you're already doing this somewhere, so adapt as you see fit)
  private var inputfield:TextField = new TextField();

  public function Main() {
    // Make sure the field is added to an on-screen Sprite
    addChild(inputfield);

    // Add the event listener.
    // I recommend adding the 'false, 0, true' params. There are lengthy
    // discussions around about this.
    inputfield.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, changeListener, false, 0, true);
  }

  // This function gets called every time the event is fired.
  private function changeListener (e:Event):void {
    trace("event");
  }
}
```

Hopefully that gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: actually the CHANGE event is only triggered in input textfields through user input, so if you change the textfield's text through code (tf.text=...) it won't be triggered.

Comment: @Cay Yes, that's exactly what the game is doing (was wondering why it wasn't working). The other problem is I am not modifying the game directly, but rather hooking into it to create my modified client :[ Options are fairly limited.