# Validate textfield before a button is pressed in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, validation, event-handling

Here is the as3:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;


wheeler.guide.visible = false;
center.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rotateHorizontal);

Stop_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopspin);

function rotateHorizontal(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,spinner);

}

var mcbtn:MovieClip;
var prizes:Array = new Array(0,180,0,40,30,0,80,75,0,10,0,25,120,0);
var prizewon:int;

for (var i:int=0; i<14; ++i)
{
    mcbtn = wheeler["btn" + (i + 1)];

    if (! mcbtn || ! prizes[i])
    {
        continue;
    }

    mcbtn.txt.text = "Earn " + String(prizes[i]) + " messages";
}

function spinner(e:Event)
{
    wheeler.rotationZ +=  15;
    pointer_txt.text = " ";

    if (wheeler.rotationZ > 360)
    {
        wheeler.rotationZ = wheeler.rotationZ - 360;
    }
    //trace(wheeler.rotationZ);
}

function completed(event:Event):void
{
    if (event.target.data.success == "true")
    {
        trace("Completed");
    }
}

function stopspin(e:Event):void
{
    var txt:String;
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,spinner);
    prizewon = -1;
    prizewon = (14 - Math.floor(wheeler.rotationZ / (360 / 14)));

    if (prizes[prizewon - 1])
    {
        txt = "You have earned " + prizes[prizewon - 1] + " Messages";
    }
    else
    {
        txt = "You have earned no Messages";
    }

    pointer_txt.text = txt;

    var phpVar:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    phpVar.code_txt = code_txt.text;
    phpVar.name_txt = name_txt.text;
    phpVar.phone = phone_txt.text;
    phpVar.Result = pointer_txt.text;
    var phpLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(phpFileRequest);
    var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new

 URLRequest("http://localhost/spin_webapp/deposit.php");
    phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    phpFileRequest.data = phpVar;
    phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

    phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completed);
    phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
}
```

Comment: May I suggest you add some inline-\comments in you code

Comment: i want the textinput of code ,phone, name to be filled first before some presses the center movieclip button.

Comment: Hey i simplified the title.. You can revert back if you like..

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an event to handle the keypress on the textfields.

Whenever a keypress occurs the keypress event handler function would check if the textfields are NULL or perform other validations.. If all is fine then set a flag like `name_txt__valid=TRUE`.

Then if `name_txt__valid, phone_txt__valid`  and `pointer_txt__valid` all are `TRUE` then make the movieclip button visible, else hide it.

Obviously the user must be informed that the textfields are in/valid, else they wouldn't realize the why the button has disappeared.

---

**UPDATE:**

*Sorry I cannot test my below code right now, but below should better elaborate what I think needs to be done..*

*Syntax for creating a listener during initialization:*
Eg.

```
name_txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,name_txt_ChangeListener);
//Also lets initialize our flags...
name_txt__valid=false;
phone_txt__valid=false;
pointer_txt__valid=false;
center.enabled = false;
```

Reference: [AddchangeeventtoTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/TextField/AddchangeeventtoTextField.htm)

Then simply add the validation logic:

```
private function name_txt_ChangeListener (e:Event):void {
...
  trace("Text field event triggered");
  //Check if text is null or invalid
  //If valid then set a flag like name_txt__valid=TRUE
  if (name_txt.text == "") {
     name_txt__valid=false;      
  } else {
     name_txt__valid=true;      
  }

  //Then make a function call to decide whether to show/hide the center button.
  showHideCenterButton();
...
}

function showHideCenterButton(){
...
  //If  name_txt__valid, phone_txt__valid and pointer_txt__valid, 
  // all are TRUE then enable the button. Else disable it like center.enabled = false;
  if( (name_txt__valid==true) &&
      (phone_txt__valid==true) &&
      (pointer_txt__valid==true)
    ) {
       center.enabled = true;
    } else {
       center.enabled = false;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: how can you make this to happen

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756138/as3-event-listeners-when-data-is-changed

Comment: what i want is to make sure that before a user clicks the center button the text inputs of code,phone and name  should be present.otherwise if they are not the text inputs have to show the user to enter the data and at the same time the center button should be inactive when the textinputs dont have information.

Comment: Check out my update.. You would have to fill in the specifics. My code will initially disable the button. When a user types some text it will remember using the flag that text field is now valid (contains some text). Then it calls `showHideCenterButton()` to check if all the textfields are valid and if yes, then it enables the center button. If no it disables the center button.